# Reading windows fax service job status in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, com-interop, fax

I have developed a web site to show job status of our fax server. I use windows fax service (fxscomex.dll interop). when I am debugging from VS2010 (using development sever), everything is fine, I can read jobs status of, but when I run my web site under IIS, job queue is always empty.

here is my code to check sent items:

```
FaxOutgoingMessageIterator sentItems = fxServer.Folders.OutgoingArchive.GetMessages(100);
sentItems.MoveFirst();
while (!sentItems.AtEOF)
{
    Response.Write(itm.Recipient.Name);
    sentItems.MoveNext();
}
```

on IIS, sentItems.AtEOF is always true.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this answer from asp.net forum and it worked!

*The identity is different from visual studio and IIS application pool. You can try to change the IIS application pool's identity to be local system or your machine/domain account or event administrator to have a try.*

however the other built-in accounts didn't work but when I set the application pool identity to a admin user, it worked.